# If we put a number of identical boxes on top of each other and apply a linearly increasing force to the bottom, will they start slipping one by one?

Tags: kinematics, friction

Let's imagine the following scenario. I put a number of identical boxes on top of each other. I then apply a constant jerk to the bottom box.

What will happen? Will the start to slip one by one? The top box first?

Let's assume the top and bottom surfaces to be large enough to cause no significant changed when slipping.

Comment: Do you mean "constant force"? Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics) where jerk is defined as $ d a/ d t $.

Comment: @jim Coming to think about it, that could be. But if the top box isn't moving with constant force, then it never starts to move.

Comment: Maybe change it to say linearly increasing force so that people like jim aren't confused. I think jerk is rarely talked about.

Comment: @user253751 Doesn't jerk exist in harmonic oscillator? The jerk having maximum value when the distance is maximal? Or is no dt involved, only dx?

Comment: A diagram would really help here.  I'm having trouble picturing where the force is being applied.

Comment: jerk is derivative of acceleration; it exists everywhere. But most people rarely think about it and it seems like jim at least got confused

Comment: @RC_23 Say a rope is attached to the bottom box, at the center of a side.and the friction with the floor is zero.

Answer (score 0):

SEE EDIT BELOW.

On the assumption you mean a constant horizontal force applied to the vertical pile of boxes...

The force applied to box 0 (bottom) is transmitted to box 1 by friction. Taking the standard model of friction = mu.N (and ignoring static friction) then box 1 will move in sync with box 0 PROVIDED the friction force is greater than the applied force.

As we go up the stack the normal force N will reduce because the weight of boxes above is less, and at some point the friction between box n and n+1 will be too small and hence the pile will slip at that junction, releasing lets say m boxes above...

SO - then the weight of boxes is reduced by m x 1 box and the friction m boxes below the original fracture becomes the limiting point, and so it repeats,

i.e. m boxes will slip off in sequential but immediate pattern.

This of course assumes that the applied force is bigger than the friction at the highest junction.

EDIT: The above incorrectly assumed a constant force.
In the case of the increasing force it can be seen that the FIRST slippage will occur when m = 1 i.e. the top box will slip first and THEN the cascade described above will allow 1 box at a time to slip....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the applied force is horizontal, then the friction force at each surface above will also be horizontal.  The normal and static friction forces increase as you go down in the stack, but the mass above each surface to be accelerated also increases proportionally.  I'm thinking the stack will tip over before slippage occurs.